# Creating Dynamic objects fails

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

Why doesn't this return a map I can iterate over?

```
function createSObjectMap()
{
    //this = {}; //AssociativeArray();
    this["divEle"]             = -1;
    this["ID"]                 = "-1";
    this["elID"]               = "-1";
}

     var sObj = new createSObjectMap();

     // The follow crashes
     // Error: "TypeError: Doesn't support this action"
     for (var x in sObj)
     {
    alert( x+": "+sObj[s] );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.

However, you wrote `s` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop variable is `x` and you're referencing `sObj[s]`.